# How to delete database records from a parent table

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my .NET 6 application with EF Core and SQL Server, I have a database looking like this:

Table `Translation`

- Id (int, primary key, not null)

Table `TranslationValues`

- Id (int, primary key, not null)
- TranslationId (int, not null, Foreign Key to Translation.Id)
- LanguageCode (nvarchar not null)
- Value (nvarchar max)

Table `FirstTable`

- Id (int, primary key, not null)
- NameTranslationId (int, not null, foreign key to `Translation.Id`)
- DescriptionTranslationId (int, not null, foreign key to `Translation.Id`)

Tables `SecondTable`, `ThirdTable`, etc.

- with foreign keys to `Translation.Id` as above

The tables `Translation` and `TranslationValues` are responsible for storing all multi-language values from all other tables, so that I can avoid cluttering my database with an individual table containing language-related data for each `FirstTable`, `SecondTable`, `ThirdTable` etc.

As you can see, in this constellation, `Translation` is the parent table and `FirstTable`, `SecondTable`, `ThirdTable` etc. are the children (e.g. `FirstTable` points to `Translation` with its attributes `NameTranslationId` and `DescriptionTranslationId`).

When I delete a record from `FirstTable`, I want to make sure that all related records (i.e. `NameTranslationId` and `DescriptionTranslationId`) are deleted from `Translation`. The problem here is that `FirstTable` is the child while `Translation` is the parent, so it's not possible to define a `CASCADE` rule.

What other possibilities are left to obtain this behavior?

Comment: *"What other possibilities are left to obtain this behavior?"* Well written set based `TRIGGER`s or handle the operations in (your existing) Stored Procedures.

Comment: Something is wrong with this requirement, because this design allows 1 parent to be used by many children. So it makes no sense to delete it when deleting a single child. That's why such operation is not supported by relational databases. You should revisit your design/requirements.

Comment: ^ agreed with Ivan. You hire a manager, and then they have two employees, when one quits do you delete their row _and their manager's row_? Why? The manager didn't quit (and there are other employees that still have her as their manager).

Comment: @Larnu do you have any examples?

Comment: @IvanStoev I see your point, but we're not going to use 1 parent for many children. So in fact it will be a 1:1 relationship where Translation is the parent and another table (FirstTable, SecondTable etc. ) is the child.

Comment: @AaronBertrand since as mentioned for Ivan it will be a 1:1 relationship, as soon as we delete the record from FirstTable, the parent record remaining in Translation will be like orphaned and won't be used for anything else.

Comment: If it is a one on one relation you can place first table's primary key as Translation table foreign key. if I am understanding it right you are just implementing self join by using other tables. First table is serving as a Bridge to implement a many to many relation between Translation and Translation You should go through your db structure and design according to the requirements. If you still want to stick with the current structure, write triggers

Comment: @BilalBinZia I can't set first table's primary key as Translation table's foreign key because there will be a lot of tables that will point to Translation table to store their multilanguage values.

Comment: Then it sounds like ID + LanguageCode would be a unique key.